# HtmlAgilityPack selecting childNodes not as expected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to use the HtmlAgilityPack library to parse some links in a page, but I am not seeing the results I would expect from the methods. In the following I have a `HtmlNodeCollection` of links.  For each link I want to check if there is an image node and then parse its `attributes` but the `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNode` methods of `linkNode` seems to be searching the parent document not the `childNodes` of `linkNode`. What gives?

```
HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmldoc.LoadHtml(content);
HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
    
foreach(HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
{
    string linkTitle = linkNode.GetAttributeValue("title", string.Empty);
    if (linkTitle == string.Empty)
    {
        HtmlNode imageNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode("/img[@alt]");     
    }
}
```

Is there any other way I could get the alt attribute of the image childnode of linkNode if it exists?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should remove the forwardslash prefix from "/img[@alt]" as it signifies that you want to start at the root of the document.

```
HtmlNode imageNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode("img[@alt]");
```

Comment: Errrm OK. That was pretty daft of me.  I thought I was missing something.  Sorry for wasting question space Thanks.

Comment: There's always plenty of space :)

Comment: You the man! A sec ago i was cursing at the HtmlAgility project, but turns out they just implemented xpath the right way :)

Comment: This didnt work for me (HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.9) - I had to use the `.//` notation (answer below)

Comment: @wal The syntax above assumes the target img is a direct child of `linkNode`. If you had to use `.//`, I'm guessing the img was a _descendant_ but not a direct child.

Answer (score 43):

With an xpath query you can also use "." to indicate the search should start at the current node.

```
HtmlNode imageNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode(".//img[@alt]");
```

Comment: The default axis is `children` to a prefix is actually not required at all.

Answer (score 10):

Also, watch out for `null` checks; `SelectNodes` returns `null` instead of blank collection.

```
HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

**if(linkNodes!=null)**
{
   foreach(HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
  {
     string linkTitle = linkNode.GetAttributeValue("title", string.Empty);
     if (linkTitle == string.Empty)
     {
       **HtmlNode imageNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode("img[@alt]");**   
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which was a really stupid design decision IMO. There's no reason it *shouldn't* return an empty collection.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619724/htmlagilitypack-documentnode-selectnodes-returns-null-shouldnt