# HtmlAgilityPack returns null

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

I have a program coded by HtmlAgilityPack and that doesn't work properly.
The Url and nodes are correct. But it has an error which refers to foreach.

The error is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It worked before. I remove HtmlAgilityPack dll and add it again. But doesn't work.
I need to access the href of a tags.

My code is:

```
string source = wc.DownloadString("http://example.com");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(source);
foreach (HtmlNode div in 
         document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='test']/a"))
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: `SelectNodes` returns null if no node can be found. You have to assign result of `SelectNodes` function to some variable and check it for null. You can check [HtmlAgilityPack DocumentNode.SelectNodes returns null, shouldn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619724/htmlagilitypack-documentnode-selectnodes-returns-null-shouldnt) question. If it worked before - then probably the HTML structure was changed, so you need to write new XPath expression.

Comment: it doesn't work. and the HTML structure wasn't changed

Comment: Does it throw the same exception? Add full exception details.

Comment: Add check `if (document.DocumentNode != null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to [Ulugbek Umirov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101449/htmlagilitypack-returns-null/23101637#comment35311584_23101449), here is your code *with* a null reference check:

```
string source = wc.DownloadString("http://example.com");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(source);

var documentNode = document.DocumentNode;
if ( documentNode!=null )
{
    var nodes = documentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='test']/a");
    if ( nodes!=null )
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode div in nodes)
        {
            // Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't have any effect